# How to use ContextReplacementPlugin on a require wrapped in a loop

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use the ContextReplacementPlugin to resolve dynamic requires occurring in this for loop: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/index.js#L7-L24

Here's the code:

```javascript
[ './binary_parser'
  , './binary'
  , './code'
  , './map'
  , './db_ref'
  , './double'
  , './max_key'
  , './min_key'
  , './objectid'
  , './regexp'
  , './symbol'
  , './timestamp'
  , './long'].forEach(function (path) {
    var module = require(path);
    for (var i in module) {
        exports[i] = module[i];
    }
});
```

I'm having trouble constructing a source regex to match this. The path being matched against the source seems to be just ".". Moreover, the context plugin seems to be called only once when there are actually 13 files being required in this loop. Can the ContextReplacementPlugin be used to resolve this issue or should I try something else?